# How to match input/output with sagemaker batch transform?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm using sagemaker batch transform, with json input files. see below for sample input/output files. i have custom inference code below, and i'm using json.dumps to return prediction, but it's not returning json. I tried to use =>    "DataProcessing": {"JoinSource": "string",  }, to match input and output. but i'm getting error that "unable to marshall ..." . I think because , the output_fn is returning array of list or just list and not json , that is why it is unable to match input with output.any suggestions on how should i return the data?

infernce code

```
def model_fn(model_dir):
...
def input_fn(data, content_type):
...
def predict_fn(data, model):
...
def output_fn(prediction, accept):
    if accept == "application/json":
        return json.dumps(prediction), mimetype=accept)
    raise RuntimeException("{} accept type is not supported by this script.".format(accept))
```

input file

```
{"data" : "input line  one" }
{"data" : "input line  two" }
....
```

output file

```
["output line  one" ]
["output line  two" ]
```

```
{
   "BatchStrategy": SingleRecord,
   "DataProcessing": { 
      "JoinSource": "string",
   },
   "MaxConcurrentTransforms": 3,
   "MaxPayloadInMB": 6,
   "ModelClientConfig": { 
      "InvocationsMaxRetries": 1,
      "InvocationsTimeoutInSeconds": 3600
   },
   "ModelName": "some-model",
   "TransformInput": { 
      "ContentType": "string",
      "DataSource": { 
         "S3DataSource": { 
            "S3DataType": "string",
            "S3Uri": "s3://bucket-sample"
         }
      },
      "SplitType": "Line"
   },
   "TransformJobName": "transform-job"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps` will not convert your array to a dict structure and serialize it to a JSON String.

What data type is `prediction` ? Have you tested making sure `prediction` is a dict?

You can confirm the data type by adding `print(type(prediction))` to see the data type in the CloudWatch Logs.

If prediction is a `list` you can test the following:

```
def output_fn(prediction, accept):
    if accept == "application/json":

        my_dict = {'output': prediction}
        return json.dumps(my_dict), mimetype=accept)

    raise RuntimeException("{} accept type is not supported by this script.".format(accept))
```

`DataProcessing` and `JoinSource` are used to associate the data that is relevant to the prediction results in the output. It is not meant to be used to match the input and output format.

Comment: thank you. I had a similar idea and was trying to print, what type the result is. but i'm don't see any print statements in cloudwatch logs. which is odd. i'm not sure what is special about the sagemaker . when i use print statment in a lambda , i can see that in cloudwatch , but for some reason i don't see it in sagemaker

Comment: also, the example i saw and posted, takes json as input and outputs json. do you know of any example that works with CSV